# Is this sub panel installation according to code?

Tags: electrical, subpanel

Am I missing something with the installation of this electrical subpanel? Concerned a little that the water outlet might be close but it's not in front of the panel and does not block access. This is meant to be 60AMP service.

[image]

Comment: You do not have working space 2’-6” wide by 3’-0” deep by 6’-6” high in front of an electric panel, which might be a problem.

Comment: Is this a flushmounted panel?

Comment: No, it's not flush, therefore strictly speaking I do have 2’-6” wide by 3’-0” deep by 6’-6” high in front of it. I don't think height and depth would be an issue only width can be argued but the water outlet cannot be moved :( and does not stick out. Thoughts?

Comment: Since moving it left/right won't solve the issue, the only other option is to place the subpanel right next to the main panel further away from the sauna. But then, why using a subpanel (as required per heater installation) and not running the wires directly from the main panel...

Answer (score 1):

The panel working space (which must be kept clear at ALL times) is

- the width of the panel (but at least 30", need not be centered)
- 36" deep stand-back distance
- 78" tall (6'6")

The working space "box" starts at the face of the panel.

If you can't move the water outlet, move the panel.  Popping it out on spacers may suffice.

I don't really grasp the idea of a water spigot on a finished and drywalled interior space in a garage for Pete's sake. If I had to do that wall, I would change it out to Tuftex white corrugated plastic roofing if it wasn't a fire rated wall.  That way it's aesthetic and waterproof, you can pop the panels off anytime to get to utilities.

Comment: Follow an industrial practice and paint a striped yellow box on the floor to make the working space area clear, given it's a garage...

Comment: Yes - I fully agree, this water spigot drives me crazy!!! Bought the house only a few months ago and asked myself the same question "who would install something like this... especially without sink!?". So the only useful way to use the spigot was to attach the hose (in my opinion).

I like the striped yellow box idea - also popping the panel out (I would need to add less than 1") is a good idea. Do I need to get a permit for this DIY work... who would know?

Comment: the lower section of ceiling id 78" high?   the water outlet is not a big  problem mount the tap on an  elbow.